Relation between magnetic moment and magnetization
I'm trying to connect all the dots between those definitions.
the magnetic dipole is defined in terms of
$m = \frac{1}{2}\int r\times JdV$
and will result in a vector potential of
$ A = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{m\times r}{r^3} $
I guess this is the same thing we call a magnetic moment
(magnetic dipole moment = magnetic moment?), which equals
$m = IA$
in case of a current-carrying wire, and which will have an energy contribution of
$ E = \int m\cdot B_{external} dV $
now, I've read that the magnetization of a material can be defined as the "local magnetic moment"
$ M = dm/dv = \frac{1}{2}r\times J_b(r)$
and that this is the same magnetization that we define by
$ B = \mu_0 (H+M) $
Now the questions -
1- how do those 2 last definitions are related?
2- how is it that in the presence of material, we get a total magnetic energy of
$ \int H\cdot B dV$ instead of $ \int B\cdot B dV$
how does the extra
$ \int M\cdot B dV$
gets canceled?
3- Is any of the stuff I said here wrong?

Magnetic moment is either defined as $\sum_a q_{m,a}\mathbf r_a$ (in a theory where there exist magnetic poles) or as $\sum_a \frac{1}{2} q_a \mathbf r_a \times \mathbf v_a$ (in standard theory, where magnetic moment is due to motion of electric charge). The equation $\mathbf B = \mu_0(\mathbf H + \mathbf M)$ is not definition of magnetization, because we don't know what $\mathbf H$ is. It's more of a definition of $\mathbf H$, in terms of $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf M$.

Also please choose one question and ask only that. Don't ask multiple questions in one post.


magnetic dipole moment = magnetic moment?

Yes and no. It is true that many texts use both terms interchangeable, like this article, however we could have other magnetic moments beyond the dipole one.
In general case, the vector potential can be written in terms of the current density:
$$
\mathbf A(\mathbf r) = {\mu_0\over 4\pi} \int {\mathbf J(\mathbf r')\over |\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|} d^3\mathbf r'
$$
In this expression, we can do a multipole expansion and write it like a series
$$
\mathbf A(\mathbf r) = {\mu_0\over 4\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over r^{n+1} }\int_V \mathbf J(\mathbf r')r'^{n}P_n(\hat r\cdot \hat{r}')d^{3}\mathbf r' \\ \equiv {\mu_0 \over 4\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\mathbf M_n(\mathbf r)\over r'^{n+1}}
$$
Each term $\mathbf M_n(\mathbf r)$ in this series is called a moment, because it is a integral of a power of $r'$. The n-th term is the $n+1$-moment vector potential. For $n=0$ we have the magnetic monopole vector field, for $n=1$ the magnetic dipole vector field an so on.
When we have very small sources with infinitesimal volume, the high moments are neglected and we usually consider just the dipole term. It is a very similar procedure that we do with scalar potential for electric sources, but there the first non-vanishing term is the electric monopole term, and here is the magnetic dipole term. This is why sometimes we say "magnetic moment" referring just to dipole term. If the source has negligible volume, you can assume it is about dipole moment.

how do those 2 last definitions are related?

Actually, the magnetic moment density of a material is a macroscopic average quantity. As defined in Classical Electrodynamics, second edition by J.D. Jackson, section 5, the field $\mathbf B$ is defined as magnetic flux density, and it is the quantity that appears in the Maxwell equations when we apply it in the microscopic domain. When we consider the Maxwell equations in a material, we are talking about the macroscopic Maxwell equations. These equations are obtained through average quantities.
Imagine that we have many infinitesimal magnetic moments distributed over the space. For the above considerations, you know I'm talking about dipoles. To obtain the macroscopic Maxwell equation we average over such dipoles to obtain a macroscopic quantity $\mathbf M$.
The Ampere-Maxwell equation in a macroscopic domain turns to be
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf B = \mu_0 \mathbf J + \mu_0\nabla \times \mathbf M
$$
Where $\nabla \times \mathbf M$ accounts as an effective current density, produced by the presence of the aforementioned microscopic moments in the material. To write it in a more familiar way, the $H$ field, called magnetic field, is defined as
$$
\mathbf H = {\mathbf B\over\mu_0 }- \mathbf M
$$
and the above equation is
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf H = \mathbf J.
$$
Despite being very similar, the equation above describe average quantities over a macroscopic domain. For practical purposes, these are quantities that we have access in a lab. But for fundamental purposes, you should remember from where this quantities came from.

how is it that in the presence of material, we get a total magnetic energy of...

By above definitions, you can see that
$$
\mathbf H\cdot \mathbf B = \frac 1\mu_0 \mathbf B\cdot \mathbf B - \mathbf M \cdot \mathbf B
$$
The first term is the energy density stored in the magnetic field alone. The second term is the average energy density that we got by averaging over each energy $\varepsilon = -\mathbf m \cdot \mathbf B$ of microscopic dipoles.
I recommend you the reading of RUSSAKOFF, G. A derivation of the macroscopic Maxwell equations. American Journal of Physics, v. 38, n. 10, p. 1188-1195, 1970.

but when considering the microscopic Maxwell equations, we find that all the energy from the magnetic field comes from the $B^2$ equation. if i consider the macroscopic definition, and swap $ B^2 =( \mu_0 H + M)^2 = \mu_0 HB + BM$. why did the last BM was ignored?

But there is no meaning to "swap" the fields like that. The correct expression is derived following the reasoning to account for all contributions:from the field and magnetic moment. Consider a linear medium, where $M = \chi H$ and try your reasoning. You will get $B^2 = \mu^2 H^2$, but the correct energy is $\mu H^2$. So if you consider the macro def and "swap" like you did, you are counting the medium influence twice

ill rephrase - the macroscopic description is still correct in the case of matter present, and the energy expression we derived for electromagnetism should not change. we could still treat the matter's charges as "free". therefore I expect the $B^2$ expression to still hold

Yes, but the magnetic field magnetize the induced currents and realize work over the dipoles, so the total energy is less than just $B^2$.
